# How does a for loop increment?

Tags: java, for-loop

The sum is -9 but i'm having trouble figuring out why. I don't understand how the j-- in the for loop will increment. It should be incremented after the body is executed, right? But doesn't the initialization of the for loop make j-- pointless? So I assume that on the 2nd iteration j becomes 2 because of i++. Could someone help look at this the right way?

```
public static void whatsTheSum(){
    int sum = 1;
    int i = 1;

    while(i < 5){
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            sum += (j - i);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? We can tell you whether you statement correctly or not, but you can help yourself better than we can by researching/testing your own theory (with debugging).

Comment: `j--` => `j = j-1` just to expand and yes it is updated after each iteration if the condition is met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how the `j--` in the for loop will increment. It should be incremented after the body is executed, right?

It's *updated*, then, yes. (The update is a decrement, not an increment.) But yes, it happens after each time the loop body is run.

> But doesn't the initialization of the for loop make `j--` pointless?

No. The initialization has `j` start with the value from `i`, and then count down while `j` is `> 0` (without changing `i`).

> So I assume that on the 2nd iteration `j` becomes `2` because of `i++`.

The second iteration of the *`while`* loop, yes. `j` will start out at `2` and then the `for` loop will run twice (for `j = 2` and `j = 1`).

Just for complete clarity, here's how a `for` loop works:

```
for (initialization; test; update) {
    body;
}
```

That's executed in this order:

1. Do `initialization`
2. Evaluate `test`, if false leave the loop
3. Do `body`
4. Do `update`
5. Jump to Step 2

Answer (score 0):

So if you have nested loops its always good to write down each and every iteration:

```
i = 1, sum = 1
1. while (i < 5) = true so
1.1 for(int j = 1; j > 0; j--) j=1
    sum += (1-1)

i=2 sum =1
2. while (i < 5) = true so
2.1 for(int j = 2; j > 0; j--)
    sum += (2-2) --> sum = 1
2.2 for(int j = 1; j > 0; j--)
    sum += (1-2) --> sum = 0

i=3 sum =0
3. while (i < 5) = true so
3.1 for(int j = 3; j > 0; j--)
    sum += (3-3) --> sum = 0
3.2 for(int j = 2; j > 0; j--)
    sum += (2-3) --> sum = -1
3.3 for(int j = 1; j > 0; j--)
    sum += (1-3) --> sum = -3
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand the requirement stated in the question above to increment j to iterate from `0 to i`, you would require something like  -

```
while(i < 5){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sum += (j - i);
    } 
    i++;
}
```

also `j++` can be replaced as `j=j+1` , `j += 1` they would have eht esame effect and the order is very nicely explained by [@T.J's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41085176/1746118)